# How to create an embed with a certain number of fields from a number?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am creating an embed which is in this format:

```
let myEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(tempDay)  
            .addFields(
                { name: '1', value: 'This is a value' }
            );
```

I want to my bot tp create this embed with multiple fields, when it is given 2 values, the start and end number. For an example, if my start number is 2 and end number is 4, it produces this embed:

```
let myEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(tempDay)  
            .addFields(
                { name: '2', value: 'This is a value' },
                { name: '3', value: 'This is a value' },
                { name: '4', value: 'This is a value' },
            );
```

Is there a way my code can do this without me manually creating this embed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
let myEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setColor('#0099ff')
     .setTitle(tempDay)  

const start = 1;
const end = 5;

for(var i=start; i < end; i++){
    myEmbed.addField(toString(i), ‘this is a value’);
}
```

This should work because .addField() can be repeated multiple times to the same embed.

if you want the last item to be included you can change the `i < end` to `i <= end`

Comment: you have a typo in `const start = 1:` and also in `comet end = 5;`

Comment: there is also another problem, your code creates one field to little. If you take the numbers 2 and 4 there should be three fields but your `for` loop only creates two.

Answer (score 0):

The [`addFields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) method takes an array of options. So what you need to do is create a function that creates your format. In this example I'll stick to two given numbers and won't bother with the value of the fields.

Now, lets create a function called `createEmbedFields` that takes the two numbes as parameters and returns an array in the needed form. The function just checks if the first number is smaller then the second number and increases it after putting it in the array. *Note: We use the `parseInt` function here because most likely you will get your numbers in a string format which we need to change to integer for this to work.*

```
function createEmbedFields(num1, num2) {
    
    let embedFields = [];
    while (parseInt(num1) <= parseInt(num2)) {
        embedFields.push({name : parseInt(num1), value: 'This is a value'});
        num1++;
    }
    
    return embedFields;
}
```

Now that we have a function we can use it to create an embed. First we need to save the returned array in a variable and then put it in the `addFields` method.

Once the embed has the required fields you can access them with [`MessageEmbed#fields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=fields).

```
const first = 1;
const second = 6;

let options = createEmbedFields(first, second);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addFields(options);
    
embed.fields[0].value = "this is a test value";
message.channel.send(embed);
```